# Gradle Test-report-aggregation plugin usage for composite build structure

Tags: gradle, plugins, build.gradle

How to use and test the test-report-aggregation gradle plugin for composite build project structure ?

I build a small project with 2 modules named first and second , and applied the plugin id in the build.gradle , but when i run the following command : gradlew testAggregateTestReport , it does not generate the aggregated html report , in the build folder of the root project.
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgWXi.png)

I have read the doc's of gradle on test report aggregation plugin. But did not get much out of it as i am a beginner.

Would appreciate your contribution for this issue.
Thanks.

[Root project's build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYahF.png)

[Root project's settings.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMOH3.png)

[first module's build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDGCN.png)

[second module's build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hztkt.png)

Comment: It would help a lot if you share your Gradle files in your question. That way we can see if you configured things correctly.

Comment: Added the gradle file's , please check the configuration's.